# how to find angle between an ellipse and a vertical line that is in the middle of the image?

Tags: matlab, angle, ellipse

i am using this code:
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/07/30/visualizing-regionprops-ellipse-measurements/
to make an ellipse around an object. How can i find the angle that is created from the center of the ellipse to  a vertical line that is in the middle of the image?

Comment: This seems like a math question, not a programming question. Suggest you take it to math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You cannot define an angle between a `point` ("_the center of the ellipse_") and a line ("_vertical line in the middle of the image_"). Reading the comment in hbaderts answer, it look like you are looking for the angle between "the major axis of the ellipse" and the "x-axis", (to then rotate the ellipse so it will be horizontal). You should edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angle between the major axis of the ellipse and the x-axis is given by the `Orientation` property of [`regionprops`](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html).
The angle is given in degrees and will lie in the range between -90° and +90°. 
I assume you are using exactly the mentioned code. There the `Orientation` value is already calculated and used for drawing the ellipse.

You get thus get the value with

```
s(k).Orientation
```

If you want to get the angle from the major axis to a vertical line, you can simply add 90° to that angle. The result will then be in the range between 0° and 180°.

Comment: can you be more specific? i want to find the angle in order to know how many degrees i have to move the ellipse and make it horizontal. i think i have to use Centroid, and MinorAxisLength but i dont know how. can you give me a programming example?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not really sure what you want to achieve. I added a sentence on how to find the angle to a vertical line. If you need any additional help, please try adding more information on what you want to do to your question, preferably with an example image. (You can provide a link to the image and then somebody with more reputation can insert it).

Comment: sorry now i understand what you  said.thank you for your help. i have another question. if s(k).Orientation has three values, how can i choose the biggest value?

Comment: i wrote this and its working perfectly but isn't there any simplier way???
`k=1;
orientation_num=s(k).Orientation;
while k<=length(s)
    if orientation_num>=(s(k).Orientation)
        orientation_num=s(k).Orientation;
    end
    k=k+1;`
end